# Downloading images in listview android

Tags: android, multithreading, bitmap, lazy-loading

I know this question has been asked before here on StackOverflow. But I've a different doubt for this scenario. The Android docs suggest using async tasks for this operation and handling multithreading problems through use of a bitmap drawable which holds a weak reference to the most recent task for an imageview.
More information regarding this at : [link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html)

The example is quite well explained, but I have a different approach to the same problem.

**MY APPROACH**

I think of using a service, with threads running inside it for downloading images corresponding to different url's which map to different imageviews. Also, a cache can be maintained with url as the key, and bitmap as the value. Then, while scrolling also, just let the old thread continue it's work, and start a new thread for present url, and put it in cache and set the bitmap by fetching from cache (url would be different so won't have the same problem as in case of async tasks where imageview itself was the key). 
One of the downsides I see for my approach is that I'd need to download all images at once (since I can't stop the service before everything finishes, nor can I keep it running for too long). 
But I guess there's something more to it, as this kind of approach hasn't been mentioned anywhere here on StackOverflow, nor on official developer docs. I'd really appreciate some help on this.

Comment: recycle view does the same , and you can use a library for image such as picasso ... have you tried them before?

Comment: It's not about how I can solve this problem, but regarding why the second approach isn't available anywhere on developer community (There must be something wrong with it). As far as third party libraries are concerned, if I had to use them, then there's no meaning left for asking the correct approach for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Volley library with `NetworkImageView` and cache. [Tutorial](http://cypressnorth.com/mobile-application-development/setting-android-google-volley-imageloader-networkimageview/)

Comment: My question is not regarding how to solve the problem (there are third party libraries for this I know), but regarding the downsides of my approach. If you could analyze it, that'd be more helpful.